# How to combine Megaparsec with Text.Read (derived Read instance)

Tags: haskell

I want to use the derived instances of Read in the megaparsec module.
How can I use 'Text.Read.read' or 'Text.Read.readEither' in a 'Parser a' ?

It needs not to be fast, but easy to maintain and to extend.
The megaparsec module is for testing my application via CLI, so many different datatypes must be parsed.

It shall work in the following way:

```
import Text.Megaparsec

readableDatatype :: Read a => Parser a
readableDatatype = 
  -- This is wrong, but describes how it shall work
  -- liftA read chunkToTokens

expr' :: Parser UserControlExpr
expr' = timeExpr
  <|> timeEventExpr
  <|> digiInExpr
  <|> quitExpr

digiInExpr :: Parser UserControlExpr
digiInExpr = do
  cmdword "digiIn"
  inElement <- (readableDatatype  :: Parser TI_I)
  return $ UserDigiIn inElement
```

What do I have to write, so that the three functions typecheck, especially `readableDataype` ?

Comment: Are you using `type Parser = Parsec Void Text`?

Comment: Yes, I'm using exactly that type.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `getInput :: MonadParsec e s m => m s` and `setInput :: MonadParsec e s m => s -> m ()` together with `reads :: Read a => String -> [(a, String)]` for that. `getInput` and `setInput` just get and set the input stream the parser is working on and `reads` takes a string and returns a list of possible parses together with the remaining unconsumed portions of the input. We also need to tell the parser the new offset in the input, otherwise error locations are wrong. We can do that using `getOffset` and `setOffset`.

```
-- For equality constraint (~)
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies #-}

import Text.Megaparsec
import Text.Read       (reads)

readableDatatype :: (Read a, MonadParsec e s m, s ~ String) => m a
readableDatatype = do
  input  <- getInput
  offset <- getOffset
  choice $ 
    (\(a, input') -> a <$ setInput input'
                       <* setOffset (offset + length input - length input'))
    <$> reads input
```

If your input is something other than `String` you will have to convert between that and `String` after `getInput` and before `setInput`.

The following is about performance concerns, so not really relevant to your problem, but maybe it is educational and it may be useful to others who may need a solution with good performance.

Converting the whole input between `String` and some other type all the time during parsing is a rather big performance bottleneck for larger input. Furthermore using `length` to calculate the new offset here is not very performant either.

To solve both of these problems need some way to be able to know how much of the input was actually consumed by the Read-parser, so that we can just drop that part from the original input instead of having to convert the whole unconsumed part back to the original input type. But the `Read` class does not have that. One could try to parse incrementally longer prefixes of the input, which may be faster in cases where the parses done using `Read` are short compared to the length of the entire input. You could also use `unsafePerformIO` to write to an `IORef` how much of the input was actually forced by the Read-parser which would be the fastest but not so pretty solution.

I implemented the latter [here](https://gist.github.com/janpath/282e337c39d486d7561c9efd1edfa654). Feel free to use it, but be aware that it is not very well tested. It does however solve all the problems with the above approach.

Answer (score 0):

That did it. Thank you! In the meantime I made a "conservative" solution of the problem by defining the constructors as strings and parsing them, without using read. That has the advantage, that you got the impressive error message of megaparsec, that tell you what symbols are missing.

Example with `read`:

```
1:8:
  |
1 | digiIn TI_I_Signal1 DirA Dectivated
  |        ^
unknown parse error
```

(only  a 'a' was missing in "Deactivated")

example with an hand written parser for the datatype:

```
1:19:
  |
1 | digiIn TI_I_Signal1 Dectivated
  |                     ^^^^^^^^
unexpected "Dectivat"
expecting "active", "inactive", '0', or '1'
```

I think I will use your code block in future datatypes.
Thank you very much!

Comment: You can get rid of the unknown parse error using `(<?>)`. E.g. `readableDatatype @Int <?> "Int"` would at least tell you that it expected an `Int`. But yes, `reads` does not give us a list of possible expected tokens, so we do loose some quality in error messages.

Comment: For very simple types that are just a list of constructors without arguments you could also derive `Enum`, `Bounded` and `Show`. Then `[minBound..]` would give you a list of all possible values, which you can then `show`. Now you have a list of all possible values together with a string representation of them, which you could easily make into a parser.

Comment: I am not really sure what you mean by “defining the constructors as strings”.

Comment: “defining the constructors as strings” just should mean that I parse the constructor e.g. "TI_I_Signal1 activated"  as two strings one after the other. The definition is normal: ```data TI_I = TI_I_Signal1 Activation | TI_I_Signal2 SomethingOther```